# Are the Lego looking figures in the picture real?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I stumbled on this picture on the Nerd Fitness blog's [paleo diet page](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2010/10/04/the-beginners-guide-to-the-paleo-diet/):

[image]

1. Are they real Lego figures? (both the mammoth and the hunters) or photoshopped?
2. If so, are they correct? Or merely repurposed (e.g. hunters are really from a Viking set, and "mammoth" is just an elephant from some Africa themed set)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are real! The minifigures all have standard LEGO body-parts. They are not from any specific theme, but mixed and matched from different minifigures. The headgear and hair-pieces are all real LEGO pieces as well. The beards are from LEGO customizer Brickforge, the spears are from LEGO customizer BrickWarriors, and the capes are standard LEGO. The elephant is also a standard LEGO elephant which appeared in several sets in the past. Here are some reference links:

BrickForge's website: http://www.brickforge.com/store/

BrickWarriors' website: http://www.brickwarriors.com/

Elephant: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=elephant1c01

Hope this helps!..(c: